# JTable keep color with the model not the row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a dilemma. I am writing a program that will view logs from an application and depending on the log level (e.g. Info, Debug, Error, etc.) the row gets highlighted a certain color. I also give the users the ability to hide log levels. So if the clicks off "show info", then all the log entries that are "Info" are hidden. The problem comes that when entries are hidden, the color they were highlighted gets pushed down to the row that was below them.

I am looking for a way that the color stays with the entry and not render the color in the next cell when the object is hidden

Here is what I have done thus far:

I initialize the renderer and set it as the default:

```
tableRenderer = new ModelTableRenderer();
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, tableRenderer);
```

and then I create my sorter:

```
sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

and I have a callback method that each of checkboxes use called `showSelected`. This takes a list of LogLevels to show and applies the filter to the sorter:

```
  public void showSelected(List<LogLevel> showList) {
    Set<LogLevel> hideSet = showList.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    sorter.setRowFilter(new RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Object>(){

      @Override
      public boolean include(Entry<? extends DefaultTableModel, ? extends Object> entry) {
        LogLevel level = (LogLevel) entry.getValue(LogModel.ERROR_COLUMN);
        return hideSet.contains(level);
      }
    });
  }
```

**ModelTableRenderer class**

This class is what I use to render the row colors. It looks at the current row and grabs the column value where the `LogLevel` exists and depending on what the log level is. This works fine when rows are not hidden.

```
public class ModelTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 425091150909034479L;

  public ModelTableRenderer() { }


  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    if (!c.isVisible()) return c;

    Color color = Color.WHITE;

    LogLevel level = (LogLevel) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, LogModel.ERROR_COLUMN);
    switch (level) {
      case DEBUG:
        color = Color.GREEN;
        break;
      case ERROR:
        color = Color.ORANGE;
        break;
      case FATAL:
        color = Color.RED;
        break;
      case INFO:
        color = Color.WHITE;
        break;
      case TRACE:
        color = Color.GRAY;
        break;
      case WARN:
        color = Color.YELLOW;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    if ((Boolean)table.getModel().getValueAt(row, LogModel.SUPPRESS_COLUMN)) {
      color = Color.BLACK;
    }

    c.setBackground(color);
    c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    table.repaint();
    return c;
  }
}
```

This is the results with no filters. All the rows are highlighted correctly
[image: With No Filters]

but when I click off "show trace" we can see now the first row is highlighted grey when it still should be green

[image: With Filter applied]

Both components (highlighting and hiding) work on their own as intended but coupling them together has been a challenge. Any help would be great.

Comment: 1. Don't invoke repaint() in a renderer. 2. Don't know why you need the "isVisible()" check. The table will only render the rows that are visible. 3. You may want to check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/). It allows you to easily color an entire row even if the data type of each column is different.

Comment: repaint is the only way that I was able to get suppression to black out a row when the click on it.

Comment: It is wrong. Think about it. You invoke repaint(), which invokes the renderer which invokes repaint() which invokes the renderer...

Comment: I realize that and am trying to come up with a better solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't image that it wouldn't work without repainting. Your renderer prepares the cell renderer, that is all. Are you saying without the call to repaint, your table isn't coloring correctly? That would surprise me. Also, the call to isVisible is bogus.

Comment: Everything is colored correctly but when i click on suppress it should be colored black. Without calling repaint it wont be colored properly until there is an update to the model so if i choose to filter something after suppressing it will color properly. i want it so that it will paint black immediately. Also i removed that visible check.

Comment: When you click on the button you should invoke repaint() on the table.

Comment: I added a `tableModelListener` which calls `repaint` since that is the only value that changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The age old problem with JTables... a view index is not a model index. Do not use a view index to lookup in the model and vice versa.

Look up [`JTable.convertRowIndexToView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToView(int)), [`JTable.convertRowIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int)), [`JTable.convertColumnIndexToView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToView(int)) and [`JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel(int)).

The indexes received in the renderer are view indexes. You are using the view index received to lookup in the model. Use the proper "convert" method first to convert to a model index, before looking up in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to TT's suggestion i was able to fix the problem. I changed my renderer to:

```
public class ModelTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 425091150909034479L;

  public ModelTableRenderer() { }


  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
    int modelCol = table.convertRowIndexToModel(column);

    Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, modelRow, modelCol);

    Color color = Color.WHITE;

    LogLevel level = (LogLevel) table.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, LogModel.ERROR_COLUMN);
    switch (level) {
      case DEBUG:
        color = Color.GREEN;
        break;
      case ERROR:
        color = Color.ORANGE;
        break;
      case FATAL:
        color = Color.RED;
        break;
      case INFO:
        color = Color.WHITE;
        break;
      case TRACE:
        color = Color.GRAY;
        break;
      case WARN:
        color = Color.YELLOW;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    if ((Boolean)table.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, LogModel.SUPPRESS_COLUMN)) {
      color = Color.BLACK;
    }

    c.setBackground(color);
    c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    return c;
  }
}
```

I also added a `tableModelRenderer` to render the suppression when the user clicks on the checkbox. Since this is the only value that changes, we can call repaint on that

```
model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

  @Override
  public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    table.repaint();
  }
});
```

Comment: *I also added a tableModelRenderer to render* - why? As I understand your logic you click on a button to filter the table. Resetting the RowFilter should be enough to cause the table to repaint() itself. If not then you should just be able to invoke repaint() in the ActionListener of the checkbox. If this doesn't work then I suggest you are doing something really strange.

Comment: This is for the check boxes within the table itself. not the filters. It is for the suppress column to black out rows.